# SAS variable with both missing and non missing observation

Tags: sas

Example data

```
id  x  y  expected_new_x  expected_new_y
1   0  .  0               .
1   .  .  0               .
1   0  .  0               .
```

My code

```
if x > =0 and x=. then expected_new_x=0;
else expected_new_x=1;
```

But I get `expected_new_x` as 1 instead of 0.

If x variable contains at least one non missing obs I want the new x variable to be coded as 0.

Kindly help me with creating the above mentioned variable using SAS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The baby picture of your data is very cute, but please post the data as text.

Comment: Are you calculating the new value for each observation independently or did you want a single value for each input variable?    Your code looks like the former (with logic errors) and your description like the later.

Comment: It's probably because you say `if x >= 0 and x = .` which can't happen. Try and change to `if x >= 0 or missing(x)`.

Comment: A number cannot be both missing and greater than 0 at the same time, so that IF condition will never evaluate to TRUE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

J_lard has the right idea. quote=J_lard:

```
if x >= 0 or missing(x)
```

In SAS missing value (.) is considered smaller than any other number. Small demonstration:

```
data test;
    input dummy;
    cards; 
    -1
    -0.7
    -0.5
    -0.1
    -0.01
    . 
    0.01
    0.1
    0.5
    1 
    ;
run;


data test_result; 
    set test;
    smaller_than_zero= dummy < 0 ;
    larger_than_zero= dummy > 0 ;
    larger_than_empty= dummy > . ;
    smaller_than_empty= dummy < . ;
run;
```

Or Alternatively:

```
%put %sysevalf(-100 > .);
```

From results or from the put below you can see that larger_than_empty is true when comparing to any number.

For more on missing values I recommend this paper: http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2005/TU06_05.PDF